# Code analysis in JetBrains Rider does not work

Tags: rider

I started using Rider 2022.1.2 for C++.

I can see errors in the current file in the Problems->Current File tab, but I don't see any errors in the Problems->All solution files tab. Solution analysis enabled.

What's wrong?

Comment: Rider is primarily for C#. If you want to edit C/C++ files, CLion is the one you should use.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/rider-unreal/